# Architecture of Redux/React app with many REST endpoints and reused components

Tags: rest, reactjs, architecture, redux, json-api

We are developing a pretty large CRM like application in using react and redux. The core part of the application mainly shows three different views for many different database objects. For example we have a users route in our system. An overview page which displays a paginated list of all users. A detail view which shows details about a single user. And relationship views which show lists of objects that are somehow related to this user for example the groups that this user is in. Multiple such views may be on the same page under the same route.

Since most of these views are very similar for all types of resources we have general ResourceOverview, ResourceDetail and ResourceRelationship views.

The data fetching also works very similar for all resources so we have a ListDataSource, ItemDataSource and RelationshipDataSource. These are classes that contain redux-thunk action creators for things like load, setPage, setOrder and reducers to handle the results and parameters of a request such as items, page, itemsPerPage and order.

This all works fine but one problem we face is that the connection between these data sources and our react components can become very complex and hard to understand. I want to be able to compose a page component that consists of multiple views that are connected to different datasources. Ideally I want to have a single container component per route that specifies which views to show with which datasources, using the connect function to give the datasources access to the store and pass the datasources down to pure components that consume the data and fire actions on the datasource.

My first question is: Does this all sound reasonable or is this design flawed?

My second question is: How do I effectively pass down such a datasource object (which helps to retrieve the correct parts of the state and allows dispatching of actions) into a deep structure of pure components without having to transfer all props down the tree all the time? Or is there a better alternative to these datasource objects?